# Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT

Tags: java, google-app-engine, search, jackson, geopoints

I'm trying to create a geopoint in my app engine application but when I try to deserialize it I got this annoying message:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: java.io.StringReader@1a21658; line: 1, column: 0]).
```

This is my JSON code:

```
{
    "id": 31,
    "name": "pepe",
    "mail": "p@p.com",
    "password": 123,
    "age":10,
    "birthday": "01-06-1991",
    "desc" : " bla bla",
    "gp": {
     "latitude": 64.124596,
     "longitude": -147.8632
     }
}
```

and this is the declaration of geopoint and my custom deserialize method:

```
GeoPoint gp;

public GeoPoint getGp() {
    return gp;
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomGeoPintDeserializer.class)
public void setGp(GeoPoint gp) {
    this.gp = gp;
}

public  class CustomGeoPintDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<GeoPoint> {

    @Override
    public GeoPoint deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        System.out.println("ENTRA");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readValue(jsonParser.getText(), JsonNode.class);

        double latitude = actualObj.get("latitude").getDoubleValue();

        double longitude = actualObj.get("longitude").getDoubleValue();


        return new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
    }
}
```

Comment: How GeoPoint class looks like? What is the package of this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `GeoPoint` class has constructor like this: `public GeoPoint(double latitude, double longitude)`. In this case we can use [MixIn feature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations). We have to create additional abstract class in which we will provide mapping between your `POJO` and `JSON`.

```
abstract class GeoPointMixIn {

    GeoPointMixIn(@JsonProperty("latitude") double latitude, @JsonProperty("longitude") double longitude) {

    }
}
```

And simple usage:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(GeoPoint.class, GeoPointMixIn.class);

System.out.println(mapper.readValue(JSON, YourRootPojo.class));
```

As you can see you do not have to implement custom deserializer for `GeoPoint` class.

Comment: which version of jackson do I need to use mapper.addMixInAnnotations?

Comment: I was using version 2.4.1 (fasterxml) but I think that this method exists since version 2.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was much simple solution.

I forgot to close brackets in my SwaggerUI request like that:

```
{
    "jobGroup": "Authorizer-CCC",
    "jobName": "Authorizer-2NO5-101"
```